# Strange behavior plotly hover

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am getting a strange behavior with plotly hovers. When using geom_segment it works fine but with geom_rect it shows only one variable.

With **geom_rect**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

test <- data.frame(C1 = c(2, 3), C2 = c(3, 4), C3 = c(2, 3), C4 = c(1, 4), C5 = c('A', 'B'))
ggplotly( ggplot(data=test) + geom_rect(aes(xmin=C1, xmax=C2, ymin=C3, ymax=C4, fill=C5)))
```

Result:
[image: geomrect]

With **geom_segment**:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(data=test) + geom_segment(aes(x=C1, xend=C2, y=C3, yend=C4, color=C5)))
```

Result:
[image: geomsegment]

I've tested with *tooltip* parameter without success (e.g. `tooltip=c("C1", "C2", "C5")`).

*Possible solution:* I can use a workaround adding the unofficial *text* aesthetic (e.g. `text=paste("C1:", C1, "<br>", "C2:", C2, "<br>", "C5:", C5)`)

Is there a more standard solution?

```
Versions: 
plotly  4.5.2
ggplot2 2.1.0
R       3.3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on `plotly`, but I have noticed this before. It appears that some parameters used for graphing will not show up automatically.

You can force them to appear by giving them a second name in `aes`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
test <- data.frame(C1 = c(2, 3), C2 = c(3, 4), C3 = c(2, 3), C4 = c(1, 4), C5 = c('A', 'B'))
ggplotly( ggplot(data=test, aes(a=C1, b=C2, c=C3, d=C4)) + geom_rect(aes(xmin=C1, xmax=C2, ymin=C3, ymax=C4, fill=C5)))
```